# Java hibernate OneToOne: which side should be the owner

Tags: java, hibernate

So i'm learning from these simple examples, there're 2 tables, USERS and USER_DETAILS, simple enough, each user has user_details and it's 1-to-1 relationship. So this sample is like this,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "USR_ID")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
   private String username;

   @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
   private String password;

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private UserDetail userDetail;

   //Setter and getter methods
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetail {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "USR_DET_ID")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
   private String firstName;

   @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
   private String lastName;

   @Column(name = "EMAIL")
   private String email;

   @Column(name = "DBO")
   private LocalDate dob;

   @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "USR_ID")
   private User user;

   //Setter and Getter methods
}
```

If you look at mappedBy, it's in the User not UserDetails.

```
Q1: so USER is the owner, if it calls save(), 
USER_DETAILS table will be updated as well ?

Q2: same examples put mappedBy in the USER_DETAILS side,
why people want to do this ?
How to determine which side to put mappedBy ?
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Q1: the behavior of the Persistance it defined with the CascadeType. Since you defined ALL, it should be saved.

Comment: Q2: In OneToOne and ManyToMany relations it does not matter where the MappedBy property is set (under regular, default circumstances). Only for OneToMany relationships it has to be the "many" side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q2:** same examples put mappedBy in the USER_DETAILS side,
why people want to do this ?
How to determine which side to put mappedBy ?

> In a bidirectional relationship, each entity has a relationship field
>   or property that refers to the other entity. Through the relationship
>   field or property, an entity class’s code can access its related
>   object. If an entity has a related field, the entity is said to “know”
>   about its related object.

There is a bidirectional one-to-one relationship in your example. Both `User` and `UserDetail` entities have a relationship field. `@OneToOne` annotation specified on both the entities.

> For one-to-one bidirectional relationships, the owning side
>   corresponds to the side that contains the corresponding foreign key.

The owner of the relationship is `UserDetail` entity. The owner has `@JoinColumn` annotation to specify foreign key (`USR_ID`).

Inverse side of relationship (`User`) has `mappedBy` attribute.

**Q1:** so USER is the owner, if it calls save(), 
USER_DETAILS table will be updated as well ?

In your example `UserDetail` is the owner. Therefore the saving process:

```
User user = new User();  // Ignoring the constructor parameters...
UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();  

user.setUserDetail(userDetail);
userDetail.setUser(user);

userRepository.save(user);
```

You only need to save the parent. It will save the child as well.